# Rails scope routing allows nil as a path segment?

Tags: internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-i18n

I want to make my Rails3.2 app i18n according to the following site and to include a locale parameter in the URL path.
(http://www.wordchuck.com/en/website/blogs/5)

I implemented as

```
scope ':locale' do
  resources :nodes
end
```

and other methods

```
def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] if params.include?('locale')
end


def default_url_options(options = {})
  options.merge!({ :locale => I18n.locale })
end
```

in my application_controller.rb.

And now I can confirm that

```
http://myhost/ja/nodes/explore or http://myhost/en/nodes/explore
```

pass, but

```
http://myhost/nodes/explore
```

got "No route matches [GET] "/nodes/explore"" error.

I wonder that could be :locale is nil.
To make nil :locale enable and defaults to "en" when :locale is nil, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

With the way you're routes are set up, the `nodes` resources require that there be a locale present.

To get around this, you can simply create more routes outside of the `:locale` scope :

```
scope ':locale' do
  resource :nodes
end

resource :nodes
```

In principle, the default locale will be used when the current locale isn't explicitly set. If you haven't changed anything in your application, this will be `:en` by default.

Otherwise, you can set this explicitly in your `set_locale` method :

```
def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params.include?('locale') ? params[:locale] : :en
end
```

Comment: Oh, to duplicate "resource nodes" with/without scope is as you say a possible way, but in fact I have much more "resources" and "match" routing statements, so isn't there any other scalable method? I suppose that setting default locale trick works only after the routing passes...

Comment: I don't know that you can define routes to have an optional scope.